# What is $E[Z|Z\ge 0]$ where $Z$ is a continuous random variable with support in $[-1,1]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a random variable $Z$,I seek an expression for $E[Z|Z \geq 0]$. I assume this is easy to get hold of but I just can't seem to get it.

As a further complication $Z=X-Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables: they are independent and from different distributions (with known, but terrible, expressions for $f_X$, $F_X$, $f_Y$ and $F_Y$ and both have support in [0,1]).  Using standard methods (see e.g. page 10 here: https://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs530/sum.pdf) I can get the PDF for Z as $f_Z(z)=\int_0^1 f_{XY}(x,x-z)dx =  \int_0^1 f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(x-z)dx$ where independence implies the last equality.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that complicated.

The conditional expectation, of random variable given an event, is defined in terms of conditional probability.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Z\mid Z\geq 0) ~=~& \int_\Bbb R z~f_Z(z\mid Z\geq 0)\operatorname d z\\[1ex]~=~& \int_0^1 z f_Z(z)\operatorname d z~\Big/~\int_0^1 f_Z(z)\operatorname d z \end{align}$$

Also you have the formula for the density function and only need to determine the support with reference to $z$: because $\{0\leq x\leq 1\}\cap\{0\leq x-z\leq 1\}$

> $$\begin{align} f_Z(z) ~=~ &\int_\Bbb R f_X(x)~f_Y(x-z)\operatorname dz \\[1ex] ~=~& \int_{\max(0,z)}^{\max(0,\min(1,1+z))}f_X(x)~f_Y(x-z)~\operatorname d x \\[1ex] ~=~& \int_{0}^{1+z}f_X(x)~f_Y(x-z)~\Big[z\in[-1;0)\Big]\operatorname d x+\int_{z}^{1} f_X(x)~f_Y(x-z)~\Big[z\in[0;1]\Big]\operatorname d x \\[2ex] &\textsf{so if we have uniform distributions:} \\[2ex] f_Z(z) ~=~& \int_{0}^{1+z}\Big[z\in[-1;0)\Big]\operatorname d x+\int_{z}^{1}\Big[z\in[0;1]\Big]\operatorname d x  \\[1ex] ~=~& (1+z)\Big[z\in[-1;0)\Big] + (1-z)\Big[z\in[0;1]\Big]\end{align}$$

Then put it together.

> For $X,Y~\mathop{\sim}\limits^{\textsf{iid}}~\mathcal{U}[0;1]$ then:
>  $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Z\mid Z\geq 0) ~=~ & \int_0^1 z~(1-z)\operatorname d z ~\Big/~\int_0^1 (1-z)\operatorname d z \\[1ex] ~=~& \frac 1 3  \end{align}$$

---

PS: [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) $\Big[E\Big] = \begin{cases}1 & : ~~~E \\ 0 & : \neg E\end{cases}$

$\Box$

Comment: Great! I feel slow today, but how do you find the limits in the second integral? You seem to do a clever change of variable but can't quite see it.

Also just to verify: the last result is an example with specific distributions for $X$ and $Y$ right? (it doesn't seem reasonable that $E(Z|Z\geq 0)=1/3$ for $Z=X-Y$ for any $X$ and $Y$ with support in [0,1], but maybe I'm superslow...? :)

Comment: @andersosterling ... right.  Somehow I had the impression you meant they were *uniform* distributions.  You will have to substitute as appropriate for $f_X(\;), f_Y(\;)$.  However, if the supports are $[0;1]$ then the bounds of the integrals are as given.

Comment: @andersosterling The boundary conditions are simply that $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$ means, when $y=x-z$ that $\max(0, z)\leq x\leq \max(1, 1+z)$ for some $z\in[-1;1]$.  So for $z\in[-1;0)$ then $0\leq x\leq 1+z~\color{silver}{\leq 1}$ and when $z\in[0;1]$ then $\color{silver}{0 \leq}~z\leq x\leq 1$